# How to Hide child model class properties name in java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a very big model class, I want to create a toString method for this model. But there're a lot of field in this model, so I try to use a Common model and Java reflection. But the output is include sub model field name, is it posible to remove this ?

I have 1 abstract model class as below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public abstract class CommonEntity {

  public String getInsertString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
      Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

      for (Field field : fields) {

        field.setAccessible(true);        

        Object value = field.get(this);
        if (value != null) {          
          sb.append("\"" + value.toString() + "\",");
        }

      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

And 2 other model extend this common

test:

```
@Data
public class test extends CommonEntity {
  private String name;
  private String last;
  private test2 test;
}
```

test2:

```
@Data
public class test2 extends CommonEntity {
  private String name2;
  private String last2;
}
```

And main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test a = new test();
    a.setName("1");
    a.setLast("2");

    test2 b = new test2();
    b.setLast2("3");
    b.setName2("4");
    a.setTest(b);

    System.out.println(a.getInsertString());

}
```

Console output :

```
"1","2","test2(name2=4, last2=3)",
```

My expectation:

```
"1","2","4","3,
```

Is it posible to remove

```
test2(name2
```

and

```
last2
```

in ouput.

Answer (score 0):

That part of the output is coming from the `toString` automatically generated by [lombok's `@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data). If you don't want it there, implement your own `toString` function.

However I have concerns about this implementation, what is the intended use of the resulting string representation? From your wording I'm worried you intend to use it as part of an SQL query, which is ill-advised.

Comment: yes, i'm intended to use for SQL query. I'm converted this data model from a very huge Json string. Please give me some advice for this case.

Comment: I don't think relying on toString to create an SQL query is the best design. Maybe define a specific method for conversion? Or better yet, use an ORM library such as [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) or [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).

Comment: My raw data in Json format. Complex structure and lot of propeties, and I want to insert to flat structure DB. I've thought about Hibernate, but if I use Hibernate, I have to convert structure Model to a flat model, and it's took a lot of effort and long source code. Is it possible or any tool to do this ?